# Rails3 - How To Render 403 in before_filter w/o DoubleRender Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, before-filter

I have a before_filter that checks the validity of an API key.  If the key is invalid, I'd like to render a header-only 403 response.

In my controller:

```
before_filter :validate_api
...
def validate_api
  if params[:api_key].present? and ApiKey.find(params[:api_key])
    return true
  else
    render head :forbidden
  end
end
```

The problem is that I get a DoubleRender error, presumably when Rails goes into the action and attempts to render the response anyways.  It was my understanding that Rails prevents execution of the action if a before_filter renders or redirects.  Is that not the case?

How do I render a header-only response in a before_filter and prevent actions from being executed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried returning `false` in the else part?

Comment: Ah wait now I see what's going on, you should just call `head :forbidden`, so leave out the `render` part in front.